# Backbone - Render Text as HTML not a String

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have my backbone app rendering a underscore template from a JSON file. I have some body copy that I want to render with a unordered list in HTML. The text keeps rendered the HTML as one whole string. Any advice to stop this?

This is what I am getting from my CMS which I have in a JSON file

```
<p>Leading provider of tax credit services and financing for productions wishing to access the state's <b>recently increased</b> 20%-25% Production Tax Credit.
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Tax Credit Administration (including filing of all forms, reports and tax returns).&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Tax Credit Advances (either during or upon completion of production)&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Deferral of up to 100% of Equipment, Camera and Facilities costs
&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;</p>
```

Here is what happens when rendered:
[image]

Comment: can you paste in some code? What do you mean with 'JSON file', is it the data or the template?

Comment: So your CMS is sending you HTML encoded text and you want to decode it before putting it into your template?

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to have `<li>code</li>` rendered as a list item instead of a raw text.

this fiddle may help: http://jsfiddle.net/fzM4N/